# Magento2 - Creating Table Rate for Fedex Shipping Options

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, fedex, table-rates

I'm new to Magento so please excuse my novice approach.

I'm trying to offer Fedex express shipping method to my customers;

**Fedex Overnight; Fedex 1 Day; Fedex 2 Day**

I'm using a third party warehouse and unfortunately I'm unable to connect via API with their Fedex Account ID.

Instead the warehouse has provided me with their Fedex Rate card and I'm trying to use table rates to set prices.

[image: Fedex Rate Card]

So I have exported the Table Rates (Weight vs Destination .csv)

However I'm not sure how to specify the zones and different speeds (overnight, 1day, 2day) within the spreadsheet

[image: Magento Table Rate]

Comment: no love? surely someone could throw me a bone?

Comment: Can this matrix rate help? https://magecomp.com/magento-2-matrix-rates.html

Comment: I would love to know the answer to this as well.

Comment: Please add it as a comment, as this is not an answer.